# React-Native IOS notifications not received: APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This has been posted before, but nothing on there solves my problem.

I am trying to implement react native notifications using the rnfirebase.io library. I am able to receive notifications on my android, but not IOS. (This is run on a physical iPhone)

app.js code to retrieve FCM and notification:

```
  async function GetFCMToken(){
      let fcmtoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("fcmtoken");
      console.log(fcmtoken);
      if(!fcmtoken) {
       try {
          const fcmtoken= await messaging().getToken();
          console.log(fcmtoken, "123")
          if(fcmtoken){
              console.log(fcmtoken, "new token");
              await AsyncStorage.setItem("fcmtoken", fcmtoken);
      }
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error,"error in fcmtoken");
      }
      }
    }
   async function GetUserPermission(){
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
   if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    GetFCMToken();
  }
  }
   const NotificationListener=()=>{
    
    messaging().subscribeToTopic('ios').then(() => console.log('SUBSCRIBED TO TOPIC IOS'))
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log('notification received')
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
          remoteMessage.notification,
        );
      });
       messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log('notification received')
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
        }
      });
       messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
        console.log('notification received')
         alert('New Notification')
          console.log("notification on froground state...",remoteMessage)
      })
  }
```

The FCM token is successfully logged. I also subscribe to a topic here, but neither sending notifications via topic or FCM are received. (The topic is received by my android phone which has the same app downloaded, though)

Everything I have tried and verified:

- The 'APNs Authentication Key' on the firebase console has the p8
  certificate added correctly.
- The GoogleService-Info.plist is correctly added
- A provisioning file and an app identifier is added to the apple
  developer console with the push notification capability enabled
- On Xcode signing & capability, Push Notifications is enabled, and on
  Background Modes, Remote Notifications and background processing is
  enabled.
- AppDelegate.m has everything that the rnfirebase.io docs say.. pretty
  much everything from there is added correctly.
- It is not a wifi problem because I am able to fetch APIs

Also, here is the exact error (this is the only error I get, so i think this is what is causing it to not receive notifications)

[Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID 'mysenderid'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.

Comment: able to resolve this ?

Comment: yes. on the firebase console, on your app configuration, instead of using just one "APNs Authentication Key" use the outdated APNs Certificates. Otherwise, check everything in my post that I tried and verified and make sure you have done that. And also make sure you are asking for permission to send notifications when the app is opened

Comment: okay, have done all this, still did not work for me